# How do I get the if statement to display the zeros ONLY the year(s) outputted an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

## How to display how many years months weeks and days someone has until inputted date

```
currentDate = datetime.date.today()
deadline = input('Enter the deadline of your project (mm/dd/yyyy): ')
deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline,'%m/%d/%Y').date()
deadline = deadline - currentDate
deadline = deadline.days

deadlineYears = (deadline)//(365)
deadlineMonths = (deadline)//(30.4167)
deadlineWeeks = (deadline)//(7)
deadlineDays = (deadline)

deadlineYears = math.floor(deadlineYears)
deadlineMonths = math.floor(deadlineMonths)
deadlineWeeks = math.floor(deadlineWeeks)

if (deadlineDays not in {1-364}):#<-PROBLEM
deadlineMonths = 0
deadlineWeeks = 0
deadlineDays = 0

deadlineYears = str(deadlineYears)
deadlineMonths = str(deadlineMonths)
deadlineWeeks = str(deadlineWeeks)
deadlineDays = str(deadlineDays)
print ('You have ' + deadlineYears + ' year(s), ' + deadlineMonths + ' month(s), ' + deadlineWeeks + ' week(s), and ' + deadlineDays + ' day(s).')
```

I can't get it to display the zeros only when the year outputted is an integer.